# Selenium on Elementary OS not working with Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, pycharm, elementary-os

I've got a problem with Selenium on my system. For some reason, it wont launch a Firefox browser window.

Here are the steps that I have gone though.

- Downloaded Selenium via pip
- Downloaded the Marionette (gecko) driver
- Added the directory of the downloaded file to my PATH.

I am still receiving the below error though.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/keva161/PycharmProjects/selenium_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/keva161/PycharmProjects/selenium_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
  File "/home/keva161/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/keva161/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x7f9bcde911d0>> ignored
```

The script the I am trying to run is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

# Tell the Python bindings to use Marionette.
# This will not be necessary in the future,
# when Selenium will auto-detect what remote end
# it is talking to.
caps["marionette"] = True

# Path to Firefox DevEdition or Nightly.
# Firefox 47 (stable) is currently not supported,
# and may give you a suboptimal experience.
#
# On Mac OS you must point to the binary executable
# inside the application package, such as
# /Applications/FirefoxNightly.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin
caps["binary"] = "/usr/bin/firefox"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig')
driver.quit()
```

I am using the latest version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm ignores your PYTHONPATH, instead it builds it based on your project configuration(s), so you need to teach it where it can find `gecko`. You can do that in either of these 2 ways:

- configure your interpreter path to include the gecko's dir, see [Interpreter paths](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/project-interpreters.html#paths)
- add the gecko's dir as content or source root (see [Content Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/content-root.html)) and select the respective check box (`Add content roots to PYTHONPATH` or `Add source roots to PYTHONPATH`) in the project's run configuration, see [Run/Debug Configuration: Python](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-python.html).